# Adobe Flex & Stage3D

Tags: flash, apache-flex, 3d, integration, stage3d

A few weeks ago I started with Adobe Flex and RIAs. After reading a lot of tuts and articles about this amazing technology I discovered Stage3D. I searched for integration of Flex and Stage3D but it seems that this piece of technology is not very famous yet. I want to develop a virtual 3D application where you could move a 3D avatar etc (Java backend)... With Stage3d (and of course a framework like Flare3d!! Awesome!) this seems to be possible. But then I thought about integrating Flex with Stage3D. For example 2D Flex components within a Stage3D application (on surfaces...) or at least combining both techniques so Flex could be used for a HUD or something like that.
Does anybody already have some experiences with this new concept ?

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Stage3D puts itself behind the display Object list hierarchy, so anything flex related you put on the display list should appear in front of the stage3D object (ie graphics).

So it should be very easy to combine the two to form a GUI.

Comment: Thanks! What do you think about Flex on a 3d surface/texture ? Or maybe a flash video surface/texture ? When you say Flex is rendered after stage3D-objects this could be very hard to do...

Comment: That would not be flex, that would look like flex, but it would be a completely different implementation. You can render stage3D to a bitmap, so you can tehnically make it part of the display list that way (so that it doesn't have to be behind all the time). However, I can't imagine a use scenario that can not be achieved with masks and alpha transparency even if stage3D is behind, and only behind display object hierarchy. Basically, don't sweat, you can do it all :) just start doing it.

Comment: Flex wasn't converted to stage3D because it's pointless, the performance speedup is about 0.3%. And absolutely everything can be achieved even with current capabilities.

Comment: Flex is rendered BEFORE stage3D, stage3D goes BEHIND the display list.

Comment: Damn, I'm wrong again, Flex is render ABOVE(AFTER) stage3D, stage 3d goes behind the display list...

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! I guess my question was incomplete... I meant to render Flex on a texture to show the texture in a 3d world, just like a 3D GUI: Imagine you are moving your avatar to a virtual PC where Flex could be used to show the GUI...

Comment: you're going to run into huge issues with filtering used by the graphics card, it will smear out the texture a lot (bilinear, trilinear etc). Leaving it on "no filtering" (nearest-neibghour) will be even worse. And you'll need to manually fire of events like mouse click to those flex components. Don't bother, you can probably use the non stage3D 3D capabilities of flash/flex to make those components look like 3D planes. and yes, rendering a movieclip to a bitmapdata-to texture is easy... BitmapData.draw(). Don't use 2D GUI as a 3D gui, it will look(feel) like s*hit. Find a true 3d solution.

Comment: as far as I know the answer is wrong. In order to use stage 3D the display list cannot be used without special frameworks like starling which reimplement it.

Comment: You are incorrect, search for "Stage3D: The stage behind the Stage". http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/how-stage3d-works.html